# How to open needed controller from Spotlight Search? In Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, spotlight

I made spotlight search in my app. I have `UIPageViewController` as `RootViewController` and seven different `ViewControllers`. I made when user found information in spotlight from my app it can open needed controller. But I made it with help `NSNotificationCenter` that I can open a needed controller. I was able to do it and I have works. I think it is wrong way and I don't know how can I make it otherwise. How can I it otherwise?

I show my realization and it works but I think that it is not a good

```
AppDelegate

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {
            let identifier = Int(userActivity.userInfo![CSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier] as! String)!
            startIndex = identifier
            notificatioCenter.postNotificationName("openSpotlight", object: nil)
        }
        return true
    }
```

UIPageViewController as RootViewController

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "openSearchFromSpotligt", name: "openSpotlight", object: nil)

}

 func openSearchFromSpotligt() {
        let startIndex = appDel.startIndex
        let startingController = viewControllerAtIndex(startIndex)! // 0
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: { done in })
    }
```

Comment: Do you need how to open particular viewcontroller when notification arise? right?

Comment: @S.Karthik No, I was able to do it and I have works. I just think that this realization is not quite correct, and therefore wanted to see more profisionalnuyu implementation of this function.